# How can I set two values in HtmlInput control

Tags: c#, asp.net, binding, controls

I have an `HtmlInputText` in an `EditItemTemplate` in a `DataGrid`, This control is bound with a value from the `SqlDataSource`

I want to set in this control two values the `JOB_CODE_ID` and the `JOB_CODE` instead of just `JOB_CODE`.

**Note**: I don't want to show `JOB_CODE_ID`, just save it to use it later in code behind.

I used to use `Tag` in the WinForms to set values such this, but in I don't know similar way in ASP.Net.

In my situation I can't use a hidden control to save the `JOB_CODE_ID` there, Is there any way to set two values in a `HtmlInputText` control ?

The code:

```
<input type="text" ID="JOB_CODETextBox" runat="server" 
                                        value='<%# Bind("JOB_CODE") %>' />
```

Thanks in advance.

@A_Nablsi, Edit:
The JOB_CODE_ID will be used along with the input value in JS function triggered on clicking the input.

Comment: The ID as in the textbox's ID?

Comment: @Drahcir: No just a value in my datasource, thanks I edited the question.

Comment: Do you want to output the JOB_CODE_ID? If no you could simply save it in either the textbox's ID or Name

Comment: No, I don't want to output it, but I need the textbox's ID to access to the control. I'll try the Name.

Comment: @Drahcir: The name has overridden and become: ctl00$ctl00$pageContentHolder$pageContentHolder1$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl05$JOB_CODETextBox

Comment: When reading the name from the code behind it returns it as you set it. It is only rendered that way in the html

Comment: @ Drahcir: So, I can't use it because I want to read the value from the code behind.

Comment: You can read it from the code behind, it returns it normally

Comment: @Drahcir: sorry, can I bound the name in the asp.net and read the actual value from code behind?? I told you what happened with me, the name has overridden.

Comment: That is it returns the name without ctl00$ctl00$pageContentHolder$pageContentHolder1$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl05$

Comment: @Drahcir: thanks, without that it returns `JOB_CODETextBox` not the value which I set.

Comment: Did you set the name on the rowdatabound event like posted in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can use a hidden field:</strike>

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%# Bind("JOB_CODE_ID") %>" id="JOB_CODE_ID" />
```

If you want to add extra data to an existing tag, you can use the Html5 data- tags. These work also in the older browsers:

```
<input type="text" ID="JOB_CODETextBox" runat="server" value='<%# Bind("JOB_CODE") %>' data-id='<%# Bind("JOB_CODE_ID") %>' />
```

You can access the `data-id` attribute, just like any other attribute.

Comment: Thanks, I mentioned that I can't use another control, and HTML5 is not an option now.

Comment: Using the data- attribute is just the Html5 recommended way. It is compatible with older browsers (works even on IE6).

Answer (score 1):

You could save the other value in the control's name in the rowdatabound event.

```
  Private Sub gvJOB_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvJOB.RowDataBound
     If Not (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) OrElse (e.Row.Cells(0) Is Nothing) Then
       Return
    End If
    Dim dr As DataRowView = CType(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)
    Dim JOB_CODETextBox As HtmlInputText = CType(e.Row.FindControl("JOB_CODETextBox "), HtmlInputText)
        JOB_CODETextBox.name = dr("JOB_CODE_ID")
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" ID="JOB_CODETextBox" runat="server" value='<%# Bind("JOB_CODE") %>' 
onclick='<%# "YourJSFunction(this," + Eval("JOB_CODE_ID") + ")" %>' />
```

Your js function should look like

```
function YourFuncName(sender, args){
// the args contains the id you need.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to trap the DataGrid's ItemDatabound event and format the two values together into the textbox.  You use FindControl to get the Textbox, then you can concatenate the values and assign them into the Text property.  Here is a link to a similar operation on Code Project:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/ItemCreated.aspx